# Filter PowerPivot field containing criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, powerpivot

I'm an accountant by trade and really just self-taught by monkeying around in Excel/VBA. I work with massive amounts of data pulled in from OLAP cubes via PowerPivot, and am trying to work through automating a process.

I'm stuck on what I think is probably a really easy question: how can I apply a filter to a PowerPivot field with "like" or "contains" a specific criteria? It's not even a dynamic requirement, but still confounding...

Here's what I've got, assuming I want to find all line descriptions that *cointain* "Data":

```
Sub DataPivot()

Sheets("Data").Select
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("DataPivot")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("[DataQuery].[LineDesc].[LineDesc]")

pf.ClearAllFilters
pf.CurrentPageName = "[DataQuery].[LineDesc].&[" & "*" Data "*" & "]"


End Sub
```

I have slightly more experience with VBA and regular Pivot Tables, but PowerPivot is just turning everything on it's head.

Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is your LineDesc showing as a Label in the PivotTable? Or in the Values area? i.e. is it on the Rows or Columns? Or is it in in the middle?

Comment: It's in neither (is that an appropriate answer ha), I'm using it solely in the "Filters" area of the PivotTable Fields. I don't need to display the LineDesc, just display other variables based on whether or not the line includes the word "Data". I was able to develop a work-around by using a calculated field in the PowerPivot model by using the formula '=SEARCH("*Data*",[LineDesc],,0)' and then setting the current page name to choose the lines with "1" in the value.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can not apply a like/contain filter in 
CurrentPageName but instead have to give/apply specif member

```
Data = "a spefic member or a list"
pf.CurrentPageName = "[DataQuery].[LineDesc].&[" &  Data  & "]"
```

However if [LineDesc] is in ROWS/COLUMNS you can

```
pf([DataQuery].[LineDesc].[LineDesc]).PivotFilters.Add2 Type:= xlCaptionContains, Value1:=Data
```

Thanks